# speech recognition pyaudio problem in vs code self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio, speech

I was trying to implement the speech to text so that it will help in my next project.

So could you please help me with speech recognition?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\PYTHON\Assisstent\speech.py", line 27, in <module>
    takecommand()
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\PYTHON\Assisstent\speech.py", line 9, in takecommand
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__       
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio   
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\PYTHON\Assisstent>
```

Answer (score 0):

install pyaudio:

```
pip install pyaudio
```